# the function of comparator and lambda expression '->' in java

Tags: java, lambda, comparator

This code is part from USACO bronze/silver division answer keys.
I had a hard time with the last question, so when the result came out, I went through the answers they provided. Here I found lines of codes I can't understand.

---

eastCows.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(j -> ys[j]));

northCows.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(j -> xs[j]));

---

what is the function of Comparator ad comparingInt?
And what does '->' operator do?
I kinda searched up for them but I wasn't smart enough to fully understand what google showed me.
please help me out

P.S
it would be thankful if you add what those two lines of codes do as a result.

Answer (score 0):

First link is your answer to what Comperator.comparingInt does and the second is about lambdaexpressions like "->"

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/comparator-comparingint-in-java-with-examples/
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html

In your example:
The general syntax for using lambda expressions is

(Parameters) -> { Body } where the -> separates parameters and lambda expression body.

The parameters are enclosed in parentheses which is the same way as for methods and the lambda expression body is a block of code enclosed in braces.